# App token returns less posts than user access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I need to request all posts on a public Facebook page. I do this with the following command:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/108062775923510/posts?access_token=[APP_ID]|[APP_SECRET]&limit=100
```

When I call this, I don't get all posts which are actually posted on that page. When I use instead a user access token, my request returns all latest posts. But using a user access token is not an option since this command is frequently executed by the server.

Does anyone know what a possible solution might be?

Comment: If you have admin access to the page, use a page access token. Otherwise, and if the posts are targeted to specific audiences, then using a user access token from a user that qualifies to see those posts is necessary; you can’t get those with an app access token.

Comment: @CBroe okay thanks for this hint. I'll check whether I can get admin access to that page and then I'll perform that request again.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks mate, this fixed it! I'm now able with the PageAccessToken to receive all published posts on that page. Cheers!